# Passing a FSharpFun from C# to F#

Tags: c#, c#-to-f#

**F#** Definition of a function in a module.

```
module ClassLibrary1.Functions

let checkThis item f =
    if f item then
        printfn "HIT"
    else
        printfn "MISS"
```

**f# unit tests - works**

```
[<TestMethod>]
    member this.TestFunctions() =
        checkThis 5 (fun x -> x > 3)
```

**in c# unit test**

```
using ClassLibrary1;

namespace TestProject
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestFunctions()
        {
            FSharpFunc<int, bool> s = x => x > 3 // error, how to declare?
            Functions.checkThis(5, s);
        }
     }
}
```

Error

> Cannot conver initializer type "lambda expression" to target type

---

**Edit**

Screenshots to help the answer.

[image]

Screenshot 3

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the lastest F# version (10.2.3), use

```
var s = FuncConvert.FromFunc(new Func<int, bool>(x => x > 3));
```

With [FX_NO_CONVERTER](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L2928) defined:

```
FSharpFunc<int, bool> s = new Converter<int, bool>(x => x > 3); 
var s = FSharpFunc<int, bool>.FromConverter(x => x > 3);
var s = FuncConvert.ToFSharpFunc(new Converter<int, bool>(x => x > 3));
```